# How to display acronym in plural form in list of acronyms with the 'acro' package?

Tags: acronyms, acro

For the acronym *transparency-enhancing technologies (TETs)*, only the plural form is used.
I have:

```
\DeclareAcronym{tet}{
    short = TET,
    long  = transparency-enhancing technology,
    long-plural-form  = transparency-enhancing technologies,
}
```

In my text, I can use `\acp{tet}` to display the plural.
But in the list of acronyms, it will show up as "**TET** transparency-enhancing technology" (singular form).

How can I configure the acronym so that the list of acronyms displays it in the plural form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plural form is to be used exclusively, the most sensible solution seems to be to make the acronym plural by default:

```
\DeclareAcronym{tets}{
    short = TETs,
    long  = transparency-enhancing technologies,
    plural =,  % explicitly disable plural
}
```

Note that I disable the pluralization by setting `plural` to the empty string.
Then, in the text, `\acp{tets}` will still work and print TETs instead of TETss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list` key in `\DeclareAcronym`, if supplied this is used in the list in place of the long form.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{tet}{
    short = TET,
    long  = transparency-enhancing technology,
    long-plural-form  = transparency-enhancing technologies,
    list  = transparency-enhancing technologies,
}

\begin{document}
\printacronyms
\acf{tet}
\acfp{tet}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! Problem is, the acronym itself is also supposed to be used in the "plural form" (so TETs with an s). If I configure it as you say, the acronym list would misrepresent the acronym as "TET transparency-enhancing technologies" – in my view that would suggest that "TET" is the acronym for the plural "transparency-enhancing technologies." Still, a nice solution for other scenarios!

Comment: @vauhochzett well sure, if you want to define an acronym which is always plural then just set the short/long form as plural and then any issue with `\acp` is your own mistake.